# How to store the availability of rooms in a hotel? PHP5/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, web-applications

I have a web form to set the days of week that a room in a hotel will be available to book it.

My doubt: what it the best way to to store that in my database?

I thought about creating 7 boolean columns one for each day of the week.

**EDIT**:  my form is the backend and is for the owners of the hotels. It sounds maybe strange, but they want to set which days of the week a room is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather store bookings in a table, one row per booking, with the columns: visitor_id, room number, start and end date. Then perform a query to see (for each room or altogether) which dates are avaiable.

Comment: no, my form is the backend and is for the owners of the hotels. It sounds maybe strange, but they want to set which days of the week a room is available.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into a structure like below. It may seem complicated but it's normalised and would scale up easily.

```
Rooms
--------------------------
id
number
type (Suite, Standard, Twin)
floor

Room_Bookings
--------------------------
room_id
reservation_id
type (customer, hotel)
date

Reservations
--------------------------
id
customer_id
total_price
paid (yes/no)
created_by (staff member?)
number_of_nights

Room_Available_Days_Of_Week
--------------------------
room_id
day_id (0 = sunday, 1 = monday etc etc)
```

- **Rooms** - a row for each room in the hotel, type could be Suite, Standard, Twin etc. (could have a Room_Types table for this and store an ID)
- **Room_Bookings** - a row for each date that a room is booked, this links to the reservation and room tables. The `type` could be Customer or Hotel. Customer for when the room is booked for a stay. Hotel could be used to block the room on any specific dates. For example if the room is having maintenance work.
- **Reservations** - a row for each reservation, by reservation I mean a stay at the hotel which could be a various number of nights.
- **Room_Available_Days_Of_Week** - this table would address you requirement of designating rooms availability based on the weekday. A row for each room and weekday that it's available.

For example, a 3 night stay would consist of a row in `Reservations` and 3 rows in `Room_Bookings`.

For your availability procedure, a room would be available if it's not booked in `Room_Bookings` and there is a row in the `Room_Available_Days_Of_Week` table that matches the required weekday.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate table for the rooms (ie, one row per room), then another separate table with a row per room / date. Insert into the 2nd table when a room is booked. To find if a room is used select from the first table with a left join to the second table specifying the date. If the columns from the 2nd table are null then the room is free (ie, nothing has been booked for that room / date yet).